# Image Change on Hover BigCommerce Site

Tags: jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

I have customized image change on hover for a BigCommerce site. The issue is that if a product image is initially set to display:none the image will not load once hover is initiated. Hovering over the products will illustrate the endless load issue I'm running into.

Researched on BigCommerce forums and Stencil theme documentation.

```
<div class="images">
    <a
      class="lazy-image replaced-image main {{image_ratio}} {{image_size}}"
      href="{{url}}"
      data-src="{{getImage img size (cdn default)}}">
      <img class="lazy-image main" data-src="{{getImage img size (cdn default)}}" alt="{{img.alt}}">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </a>
    {{#if product.images.[1]}}
    <a
      class="lazy-image replaced-image second {{image_ratio}} {{image_size}}"
      href="{{url}}"
      data-src="{{getImage product.images.[1] img size (cdn default)}}">
      <img class="lazy-image main" data-src="{{getImage product.images.[1] img size (cdn default)}}" alt="{{img.alt}}">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </a>
    {{else}}
    <a
      class="lazy-image replaced-image second {{image_ratio}} {{image_size}}"
      href="{{url}}"
      data-src="{{getImage img size (cdn default)}}">
      <img class="lazy-image main" data-src="{{getImage img size (cdn default)}}" alt="{{img.alt}}">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </a>
    {{/if}}
    </div>
```

I'm wanting the product images to change between index [0] & [1] on hover.

Comment: Hey there, could you share your JS as well?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to forget that!

Comment: <script>

$(window).load(function(){ $(".images").trigger('mouseover'); })

/*
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)

function myFunction() {
    $(".images").find(".second").hide();
}

myFunction();
*/
$(".images").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".main").hide();
        $(this).find(".second").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".main").show();
        $(this).find(".second").hide();
    });

</script>

Comment: Thanks! I might suggest going about this in a slightly different way. I'll detail in an answer below, but let me know if it's a requirement to swap the elements with jQuery and we can go from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" events on a single image tag to swap the image source between images[1] and the default product image:

```
<img class="card-image lazyload" onmouseover="this.src='{{getImage images.[1] img size (cdn default)}}'" onmouseout="this.src='{{getImage image 'productgallery_size' (cdn default)}}'" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage image 'productgallery_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" title="{{image.alt}}">
```